# Javascript Animation Framework

Tags: javascript, animation, jquery-animate, cocos2d-js, web-animations

I am looking for a javascript animation framework. I have found some:

http://www.pixijs.com/

http://phaser.io/

http://paperjs.org/

These all are good.

But I would like a GUI based animation creater framework, so that I can create translation, scale and frame animations. That will allow me easily create basic animations without having to write much code.

Something like [cocos studio](http://codezine.jp/static/images/article/8468/8468_1-3.gif) for cocos2d.

If you guys, know any such framework, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you need some animations libraries, here are some good ones:

1. Greensock: https://greensock.com/
2. Velocity.js: http://julian.com/research/velocity/

If you want to create animations in a GUI, things to consider:

1. Adobe Edge (paid): https://creative.adobe.com/products/animate
2. Bouncejs: http://bouncejs.com/
3. CSS Animate: http://cssanimate.com/

Comment: bounce.js is very useful for me

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very simple library based on request animation frame that can basically animate anything you want as it only returns number values over specified time according to the specified easing.

https://github.com/alanbo/animate.js

Answer (score 0):

I have created one, which is very simple and small

https://github.com/allenhwkim/jsanimation

Usage

```
import {slideInRight} from 'jsanimation';
slideInRight(el);
```